# Azure Functions - Nuget package downloaded but not found at runtime - Autofac 4.4.0

Tags: azure, nuget, azure-functions

Once again I am having issues with precompiled functions - this time with Nuget package dependencies.

I added a project.json file and my dependency (Autofac 4.4.0) was restored successfully - confirmed via the logs.

On running of my precompiled function, however, the Autofac dependency causes an exception to be thrown. I have tried restarting etc.

See log extract:

`2017-03-08T11:23:20.540 Restoring packages.
2017-03-08T11:23:20.540 Starting NuGet restore
2017-03-08T11:23:23.044 Restoring packages for D:\home\site\wwwroot\FindNewFairplayXmlFiles\project.json...
2017-03-08T11:23:23.790 GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/autofac/index.json
2017-03-08T11:23:24.727 OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/autofac/index.json 942ms
2017-03-08T11:23:24.790 GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/autofac/4.4.0/autofac.4.4.0.nupkg
2017-03-08T11:23:25.717 OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/autofac/4.4.0/autofac.4.4.0.nupkg 926ms
2017-03-08T11:23:26.809 Installing Autofac 4.4.0.
2017-03-08T11:23:30.230 Committing restore...
2017-03-08T11:23:30.246 Writing lock file to disk. Path: D:\home\site\wwwroot\FindNewFairplayXmlFiles\project.lock.json
2017-03-08T11:23:30.420 D:\home\site\wwwroot\FindNewFairplayXmlFiles\project.json
2017-03-08T11:23:30.420 Restore completed in 7614ms.
2017-03-08T11:23:30.464 
2017-03-08T11:23:30.464 NuGet Config files used:
2017-03-08T11:23:30.464 C:\DWASFiles\Sites\acutefunc\AppData\NuGet\NuGet.Config
2017-03-08T11:23:30.464 
2017-03-08T11:23:30.464 Feeds used:
2017-03-08T11:23:30.464 https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
2017-03-08T11:23:30.511 
2017-03-08T11:23:30.511 Installed:
2017-03-08T11:23:30.511 1 package(s) to D:\home\site\wwwroot\FindNewFairplayXmlFiles\project.json
2017-03-08T11:23:30.558 
2017-03-08T11:23:30.558 
2017-03-08T11:23:30.823 Packages restored.
2017-03-08T11:23:31.151 Script for function 'FindNewFairplayXmlFiles' changed. Reloading.
2017-03-08T11:23:31.151 Compilation succeeded.
2017-03-08T11:24:37.960 Function started (Id=9c8e8e66-0419-43a7-8b81-a30e6a138b72)
2017-03-08T11:24:38.007 Function completed (Failure, Id=9c8e8e66-0419-43a7-8b81-a30e6a138b72)
2017-03-08T11:24:38.054 Exception while executing function: Functions.FindNewFairplayXmlFiles. mscorlib: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. Acute.Compiled.Functions: Could not load file or assembly 'Autofac, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17863af14b0044da' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: running locally or in Azure?

Comment: In Azure Functions, deployed via github continuous deploy

Answer (score 2):

Added this information to your GitHub question as well, But with the pre-compiled scenarios, the package references (which is a compilation feature, for dynamically compiled functions) do not play a role and you're expected to publish/deploy the build artifacts from your assembly's compilation, including dependencies.

Please ensure the required assemblies are deployed with your pre-compiled function assembly and give it another try.

Comment: Such a shame it is not supported -- I am looking for the same thing.

Comment: This is by design. The package restore is a build time activity, which doesn't happen with pre-compiled functions. In those cases, you want to deploy those assemblies to ensure a stable set of dependencies, as opposed to something that will be restored at run time.